# Externalize log4j.properties file using command line Java

Tags: java, linux, shell, log4j

I am trying to externalize the `log4j.properties` file. I am using `-Dlogging.config` Java argument but It is not working. Also there is no other `log4j.properties` file in jar file also. I am not sure what i am doing wrong. At console I am getting below error and no log file is getting generated at the specified location defined in `log4j.properties` file.

console error:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.techburps.gdriveconnect.GdriveConnectApplication).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

Linux Shell command (run from .sh file):

```
java -Dlogging.config="file:..conf/log4j.properties" -cp ../conf/*:../lib/* com.techburps.gdriveconnect.GdriveConnectApplication $DUMP_FILE
```

what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

The property `logging.config` is used by [Spring Boot](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.core.logging.config).

Log4j 1.2 uses the `log4j.configuration` system property (cf. [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html#Default_Initialization_Procedure)). Therefore you want to use:

```sh
java -Dlog4j.configuration=file:../conf/log4j.properties ...
```

Comment: Still same error

Comment: Try with `file:../conf/log4j.properties`.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting the debug option, I found that It was not able to find the "../conf/log4j.properties"  in the classpath. That's because maybe I was not adding this path using "-cp" properly. So to fix It I corrected the -cp option and also removed this log4j property completely. Now with below change Its working fine.
"java -cp .:../conf:../lib/* com.techburps.gdriveconnect.GdriveConnectApplication $DUMP_FILE"